# Symbol already defined

Tags: c++

Having 2 simple files like that:

Main.c:

```
#include "Initialization.cpp"
int main() {    
    return 0;
}
```

and Initialization.cpp:

```
int main2() {
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting en error:

```
..."int __cdecl main2(void)" (?main2@@YAHXZ) already defined in Initialization.obj...
```

What's peculiar when i complied the program the first time everything was ok. After recompilation this error starts appearing.

PS. I'm using Visual Studio c++ 2019

Comment: Don't `#include` cpp files, only header files. Compile cpp files individually, and then link the resulting object files together to make the final executable.

Comment: How did you compile? (compile command and what compiler version?)

Comment: The compiler sees `Main.c` as `int main2() { return 0; } int main() { return 0; }` after preprocessing. If you compile `Initialization.cpp` in addition to `Main.c`, this should explain, why `main2` is available from 2 object files...

Comment: @TonyTannous  I'm using Visual Studio c++ 2019 as i've added in my question.

Comment: @fabian Ok, but Why does the first compile runs OK, while recompiling NOT?

Comment: Seems like some issue with your Makefile. If you just compile Main.c things should work.

Comment: Technically compiler shouldn't have a problem here. It's the linker that discovers these issues. Compiling `Main` as a C or C++ code seems to make a difference. Probably different name mangling saved you the first time...

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor copies everything in the include file into `Main.c` which will look

```
int main2() {
    return 0;
}

int main() {    
    return 0;
}
```

Both `Initialization.o` and `Main.o` now have definition for
`main2()`. Thus, you break the one definition rule and invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, but Why does the first compile runs OK, while recompiling NOT?